Unable to edit DOM using javascript from console (Firefox, pop!OS)
I am working on pop!OS using Mozilla Firefox.
When I open developer options console and try to make changes to the webpage(specifically changing the seasonal photo on google.com to that of a cat from pixabay.com) it doesn't work. But then there is this error I keep seeing anytime I open developer options on a webpage.

Content-Security-Policy: (Report-Only policy) The page’s settings would block an event handler (script-src-attr) from being executed because it violates the following directive: “script-src 'nonce-MhEN2Yr7TKzGZSuX-cGEHw' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:”
Source: _rtf(this)

and...

Content-Security-Policy: (Report-Only policy) The page’s settings would block a script (script-src-elem) at https://www.gstatic.com/_/mss/boq-identity/_/js/k=boq-identity.IdentityRotateCookiesHttp.en_US.whKIJEZ_mPQ.es5.O/am=DAY/d=1/rs=AOaEmlGK7LdK0XwTFbJAAAPAYXm_ieQaeg/m=hfcr from being executed because it violates the following directive: “script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob: data:”

Error showing when console is opened

DOM remain the-same after JavaScript code was instructed to change the holidays picture

But, when I go manually into the HTML I am able to make changes (used the inspector tool to select the image and changed the 'src' to that of the cat image.)
image showing the google.com seasonal picture changed to a cat picture

I tried this on chromium and everything was working as should. That is, I was able to edit the DOM manually and with JavaScript from the console. Until I logged into my gMail, the another similar error was shown at the top.
Error from chromium developer tools console

But the primary problem is why Firefox gives me that error.
I did some search myself and got things about csp, I played with that a bit from about:config but didn't help either.
I went through the developer tools and played around to see if it was about anything that was checked or unchecked but no positive results
(p.s. I am new to using developer tools and only following a tutorial).
I uninstalled Firefox and installed it again, still the error messages at the top of the console were still there. I installed flatpak version of Firefox the-same problem was still there. I restarted my PC and still.
NOTE: I am running my javascript code in the live console(developer options, click the console tab and typed it in there)

It is a linux distro, pop! OS

These "errors" appear to be report-only - which means, these CSP restrictions are not currently getting applied, but only reported back to the site owner. I'm getting similar errors in Firefox on Mac, but document.querySelector('img') typed into the console selects the image fine. Is the problem unique to this pop!OS thing?

If the errors appear as soon as you open devtools, then you have not caused them. They are merely logged there from something else that violated the CSP. Also, the error says that it is a reporting-only policy. That means that nothing is blocked. It's just reported to the site as a violation. FWIW, I don't get the CSP errors. Maybe you have an extension trying to do something. Meanwhile, I could enter that JS in my console and swap out the img. (FF133)

Thank you, but i am not sure this is unique to my OS, because on chromium it works fine only until i log into my g mail. Thank you once again.
